# Regex query with fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) error

Tags: java, android, regex, couchbase-lite

I am using couchbase lite version `android-ee:2.1.2`. I stored some data in local couchbase lite database. Now, I am trying to query data from local couchbase lite database with the help of regex query like,

```
Query query = QueryBuilder
                .select(SelectResult.property("info"))
                .from(DataSource.database(localDatabase))
                .where(Expression.property("info").regex(Expression.string("^v" + "_" + "(4.6.2|1.7.7)" + "_" + "[123]" + "_" + "[12345678]")));
```

And my database looks like,

```
v_1.7.7_1_3
v_1.7.5_1_3
v_4.7.1_2_8
v_4.7.1_1_8
v_4.7.2_2_8
v_4.7.2_2_8
v_4.7.1_1_8
v_4.7.1_2_8
v_4.7.5_1_8
v_4.9.3_1_1
...
...
...
and so on many entries
```

To understand database structure let's take an example of `v_1.7.7_1_3` here `v` can be defined as a just value, `1.7.7` is tag then `1` is parent class(this can be of type 1,2 and 3) and then `3` is child class(this can be of type 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 and 8).

Now user can select multiple tags, parent classes, and child classes as a choice. Then I have to query data from local couchbase lite according to parameters selected respectively. Currently, as I stated above I am trying to query data with the help of regex as like,

For example, let a user selected tag `4.6.2` and `1.7.7`, then the parent classes are 1,2 and 3 and then child classes 1-8. So my query will be like,

```
"^v" + "_" + "(4.6.2|1.7.7)" + "_" + "[123]" + "_" + "[12345678]"
```

I already tried this query on https://regex101.com where it is working perfectly, but not with couchbase lite.

Although the application is just crashing with a fatal error,

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 25543 (.mains.activity)
```

Here some logs,

```
V/Query: Query encoded as {"WHAT":[[".info"]],"WHERE":["regexp_like()",[".info"],"^v_(4.6.2|1.7.7)_[123]_[12345678]"]}
I/LiteCore [Query]: {Query#3}==> N8litecore11SQLiteQueryE 0x7f5a2d9098
I/LiteCore [Query]: {Query#3} Compiling JSON query: {"WHAT":[[".info"]],"WHERE":["regexp_like()",[".info"],"^v_(4.6.2|1.7.7)_[123]_[12345678]"]}
I/LiteCore [Query]: {Query#3} Compiled as SELECT fl_result(fl_value(body, 'info')) FROM kv_default WHERE (regexp_like(fl_value(body, 'info'), '^v_(4.6.2|1.7.7)_[123]_[12345678]')) AND (flags & 1) = 0
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 28308 (.mains.activity)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hours of working and research on couchbase lite, I got this. First thing there is nothing wrong with regex query it is working fine.

And the second one is while checking my database I realized that info field on which I am querying data is EMPTY or NULL in some database entries. So I added a condition in my query like,

```
Expression.property("info").notNullOrMissing()
```

So when info is available then I am performing my regex query as like,

```
.where(Expression.property("info").notNullOrMissing().and(Expression.property("info").regex(Expression.string("^v" + "_" + "(4.6.2|1.7.7)" + "_" + "[123]" + "_" + "[12345678]"))))
```

And it is working perfectly without any fatal signal error or anything.

**Note: -** Another thing is that info field in my database is defined as index, so maybe I am querying data on index field and it is getting null or empty that's why I am getting a fatal signal error (I am still searching, is this logic correct or not.)

Answer (score 1):

I think, your regex query seems to be fine. You can validate with the below unit test case.

```
@Test
public void testRegex() throws Exception {
    MutableDocument doc1 = new MutableDocument("doc1");
    doc1.setValue("version", "v_1.7.7_1_3");
    db.save(doc1);

    MutableDocument doc2 = new MutableDocument("doc2");
    doc2.setValue("version", "v_1.7.5_1_3");
    db.save(doc2);

    MutableDocument doc3 = new MutableDocument("doc3");
    doc3.setValue("version", "v_4.7.1_2_8");
    db.save(doc3);

    MutableDocument doc4 = new MutableDocument("doc4");
    doc4.setValue("version", "v_4.7.1_1_8");
    db.save(doc4);

    MutableDocument doc5 = new MutableDocument("doc5");
    doc5.setValue("version", "v_4.7.2_2_8");
    db.save(doc5);

    MutableDocument doc6 = new MutableDocument("doc6");
    doc6.setValue("version", "v_4.6.2_2_8");
    db.save(doc6);

    Query q = QueryBuilder
            .select(SelectResult.property("version"))
            .from(DataSource.database(db))
            .where(Expression.property("version").regex(Expression.string("^v" + "_" + "(4.6.2|1.7.7)" + "_" + "[123]" + "_" + "[12345678]")));

    List<Result> results = q.execute().allResults();
    // since the doc1 and doc6 passes the regex. 
    assertEquals(results.size(), 2);
}
```

Comment: You are saying that this test does not work in your environment?

Comment: P.S. If you are thinking of using the EE version in production then you will be entitled to premium support once you buy the required license.  It will provide you with more tailored answers than here :)